# "are being made to speak, in the course of which"

Tags: grammar

*Thinking has come to life again; the cultural treasures of the past, believed to be dead, are being made to speak, in the course of which it turns out that they purpose things altogether different from the familiar, worn-out trivialities they had been presumed to say.*

Source: Mark Lilla: The Reckless Mind, p. 12.

I am puzzled by the relative clause in the above sentence ("in the course of which it turns out"). Is it in English common that the relative sentence modifies participle which I think is this case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes: non-restrictive relatives allow a wider range of antecedents than restrictive ones, including participial clauses.

But I’d say that “which” refers not just to the participial clause, but to the whole main clause (in bold):

*Thinking has come to life again; **the cultural treasures of the past, believed to be dead, are being made to speak**, in the course of which it turns out that they purpose things altogether different from the familiar, worn-out trivialities they had been presumed to say*.

Answer (score 1):

That is a legitimate usage.

> I was speaking with the mayor, in the course of which [i.e. the
>   referenced conversation] I asked him about the downtown parking lot.

There is no explicit noun reference for *which*.

An alternative would be "in the course of doing so..."

[[image: The Dublin Journal of Medical Science (1836-1845)., Volumes 15-16[1]]
https://books.google.com/books?id=HPY1AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA291&dq=%22during+the+course+of+which%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjClcGSm4nKAhWE7yYKHSvODWwQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=%22during%20the%20course%20of%20which%22&f=false